# sscanf till reach some chars

Tags: c, json, parsing, scanf

I am trying to do kind of a parser in C to read a JSON.

I need to parse a table like this:

```
char rosa[1024] ="\"358\":{\"myItem\":12,\"1\":{1,0},\"2\":{0, 0}},\"352\":1";
sscanf(rosa, "%[}}]s",rosa);
```

Output: `"358":{"myItem":12,"1":{1,0`

I need to extract first Key-Value.
So, I tried to do a `sscanf` but it reads until first `}`, not till `}}`.

Any suggestion?

Best regards.

Comment: Use an existing JSON parsing library.

Comment: Though that `rosa` a) isn't valid C, b) isn't valid JSON...

Comment: Please don't try to parse JSON yourself, in any way. That's just going to be be too complex. Use an existing library to handle it all for you.

Comment: cant use a json library for this project sry; and no, no problem with source and dest

Comment: What is your full and complete assignment? Is it a school/learning exercise? Then for what kind of course or subject? What are your requirements? What are your limitations? Please update your question with all underlying details and context.

Comment: posted; (some programmer dude)--> its for a project; my limitation is that i cannot use external library. I need to do a sscanf to read till 2 chars detected ( }} ); limitation--> sscanf only reads 1 char

Comment: The problem is that `scanf` and its related functions aren't really good for arbitrary parsing, and definitely not able to handle nested structures. You need to come up with a more complex but better suited way to parse the string. Exactly what to do and how to do it depends a lot on your assignment and what you have been taught in class. Talk to your teachers about the assignment if there is anything that is unclear for you. If it's not a class but an assignment at work then it *also* depends on the requirements, and you need to talk to your team about it.

Comment: Not related to the main problem, but `%[...]s` is wrong. `[]` is not a modifier for `%s` but a different format specifier. Your format string would expect to get a `'s'` as last character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `strstr(rosa, "}}")` to detect if and where `rosa[]` contains `}}`.

```
char *end = strstr(rosa, "}}");
if (end) {
  printf("<%.*s>\n", (int) (end - rosa) + 2, rosa);
} else {
  printf("Not found\n");
}
```

Comment: Thats it what I need!! Thank you sooooo much :) strstr is the final solution.

Comment: @rosa.tarraga Note that this will only work for this specific case. What if the next input doesn't have nested structures? What if there's a tripple nesting with an ending `}}}`? What if you have multiple nestings inside the object you try to extract, and there's a `}}` inside that object (like `\"123\":{\"234\":{\"345\":{\"456\":1}},\"567\":2}`)?

Comment: Np, it wont happen, its a very specific case; in an ideal world, 2}} would work in sscanf but the strstr will be ok for me in this case.